# Laravel joining two tables mismatching columns with same name

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables -

users (id, establishment_id, name...)

establishments (id, district_id, name,...)

I want all the users with district_id = 1. I am not using eloquent relationship in any model.

I tried as

```
$users = User::join('establishments', 'establishments.id', '=', 'users.establishment_id')->where('district_id', '=', $admin_district_id)->where('is_active', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
```

but it returns establishment name instead of users name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with -

```
$users = User::join('establishments', 'establishments.id', '=', 'users.establishment_id')->where('district_id', '=', $admin_district_id)->where('is_active', '=', 1)->select(array('users.*'))->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the column name for `name` is ambiguous.

One option is to give explicitly alias for users name as user_name

```
$users = User::join('establishments', 'establishments.id', '=', 'users.establishment_id')
->select('users.name AS user_name', 'establishments.name AS establishment_name', 'users.*', 'establishments.*')
->where('district_id', '=', $admin_district_id)
->where('is_active', '=', 1)
->paginate(3);
```

In order to `users table name` you can now user `user_name`